# Can't pick day if inline

Tags: react-datepicker

I can't not pick a day at the weekend. The cursor is not changed. Only days in the width of the div, where the datepicker is in, can be picked. How I can fix this? I give an example using bootstrap to show the problem.

```
import React from "react";

import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

class KSTabs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.onOpenDatepicker = this.onOpenDatepicker.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            startDate: Date.now(),
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    onOpenDatepicker = () => {
        this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
    };

    handleChange(date) {
        this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen, date: date });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-2">
                    <button onClick={this.onOpenDatepicker}> Open</button>
                    {this.state.isOpen && (
                    <DatePicker
                        selected={this.state.startDate}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        inline
                        />
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-2" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default KSTabs;
```

**Edit**

When the calendar is open, then I can select the first day on the left side, but I can't select the first date on the right side. The div column has a width of 185px and the datepicker 240px. Every days which are outside of the 185px are not selectable.

Comment: Give more detail what is error